# 4-velocity in §2.8 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler

Tags: special-relativity, energy, photons, momentum

At section §2.8 of their "Gravitation", Misner, Thorne and Wheeler calculate the energy of a photon emitted at the rim of a turning centrifuge in a Mössbauer effect experiment. In the emitter's frame, they say the photon's energy is *E<sub>e</sub> = –**pu<sub>e</sub>***, where ***p*** is the 4-momentum of the photon and ***u<sub>e</sub>*** is the emitter's 4-velocity.

What is the emitter's 4-velocity doing there? Shouldn't it be the velocity of the photon?

Comment: It's explained in the solution : That this formula works can be readily verified by recalling that, in the emitter's frame, $\:u^0_e=1\:$ and $\:u^j_e=0, j=1,2,3\:$
; so
$$
E_e=-p_a u_a=-p_0=+p^0
$$
in accordance with the identification ''(time component of 4-momentum) = (energy)''. I suppose you know that the inner product of two 4-vectors is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Well, apparently the book is not intended for me then. I have a modest background on linear algebra and basic tensor calculus, but I now see how underfamiliarized I am with 4-vectors. I had read the part which says that this can be "readily verified". I feel quite unready to verify it :(

By the way, the authors leave this question as an exercise on the next page, so perhaps it's not so straightforward as they suggest at first... Yet, as they offer no solution, it's clearly assumed that the reader should be able to figure this out by himself

Comment: Well, don't leave this case to disappoint you. They write : ''*Notice that this solution made no reference whatsoever to Lorentz transformations-
they have not even been discussed yet in this book! The power of the geometric,
coordinate-free viewpoint is evident!*'' This is unreasonable. A 4-vector is a 4-dimensional quantity that under a Lorentz transformation is transformed as the 4-dimensional space-time position vector, not a usual vector in Euclidean $\:\mathbb R^4$. And the solution they provided is based on the Lorentz invariance of the inner   Minkowski  product of two 4-vectors.

Comment: Finally, to study 4-vectors means to study Special Relativity and especially Lorentz transformations. By the way, Welcome to PSE.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I went too fast through the basics. Anyway, I'll insist a little more before stepping back to Special Relativity. I'm glad you said this about MTW's unreasonableness on that section. I had a feeling that they were trying to do math without doing math! (And their choice of leaving the crucial demonstrations as exercices is not helping me a lot, hehe). Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty standard notation, but it can be a little bit of a tricky concept the first time you run into something like this.

In the emitter's frame, and using natural units, the four-momentum is $\mathbf{p}=(E_e, E_e)$ where the energy in this frame is $E_e$. We can clearly get this by multiplying $E_e=-(E_e,E_e)(1,0)=-\mathbf{p} \mathbf{u_e}$

The weird thing about this is that $-\mathbf{p} \mathbf{u_e}=E_e$ is an invariant, even though in general $E$ is not an invariant in general. In other words, not all frames will agree that $E_e$ actually represents the energy of that particle, but all frames will agree that an energy detector moving at $ \mathbf{u_e}$ will measure the number $-\mathbf{p} \mathbf{u_e}$ for the energy of that particle. In frames where $\mathbf{u_e} \ne (1,0)$ this number $E_e$ will not be the actual energy of the particle, but due to length contraction and time dilation of the measuring device, it is what will be measured.

> What is the emitter's 4-velocity doing there?

It four-velocity of the device measuring the energy of the photon. In this case the emitting atom.

You will see this kind of construction often. Basically you will obtain an invariant measure of some quantity where the measurement is invariant because we have specified the motion of the measuring device using some timelike four-velocity.

Comment: Thanks, Dale. I think I'll have to study 4-vectors better before diving into this mysterious world. Well, I can console myself with having asked a not so bad question, for the authors themselves leave it as an exercise later on.